# Change what print(Object) displays in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, printing, swift2

I am trying to make my class `Digit` display the `num` variable whenever print is called on that object, in Swift 2.0. I thought this might be done with a description variable, but no luck.

```
class Digit {

  var num: Int
  var x: Int
  var y: Int
  var box: Int
  var hintList: [Int] = []
  var guess: Bool = false

  var description: String {
    let string = String(num)
    return string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It isn't enough to just add a `description` variable. You need to also state that your class conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` (formerly known as `Printable` in earlier Swift versions).

If you command click the `print` function, you find the following description.

> Writes the textual representation of `value`, and an optional newline,
>   into the standard output.
>
> The textual representation is obtained from the `value` using its protocol
>   conformances, in the following order of preference: `Streamable`,
>   `CustomStringConvertible`, `CustomDebugStringConvertible`.  If none of
>   these conformances are found, a default text representation is constructed
>   in an implementation-defined way, based on the type kind and structure.

The part of which that matters here being that objects passed to `print` are not checked for whether or not they have a `description` method, but instead checked for things like whether or not the conform to protocols like `CustomStringConvertible` which offer data to be printed.

That being said, all you need to do in this case is specify that your class conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` since you've already added a `description` variable. If you hadn't already added this, the compiler would complain because this protocol requires that the `description` variable be implemented.

```
class Digit: CustomStringConvertible {
    var num: Int
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
    var box: Int
    var hintList: [Int] = []
    var guess: Bool = false

    var description: String {
        let string = String(num)
        return string
    }
}
```