# Swift : How to assign object content instead of the type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, object

I want to assign an array of objects to an array variable in the class named : *SchoolClass*

supposing that the name of my project is ***MyProjectName*** and that I have the following classes :

```
import Foundation

class Student {

    var name : String
    var age : Int

    init(name : String, age : Int) {
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
    }
}

class SchoolClass {

    var students : [Students]
    var speciality : String

    init (students : [Students], speciality : String) {
        self.students = students
        self.speciality = speciality
    }
}
```

And that I fill them with some data:

```
var studentsClassA = [Student]()
studentsClassA[0] = Student(name: "Toto", age: 1)
studentsClassA[1] = Student(name: "Titi", age: 2)

var studentsClassB = [Student]()
studentsClassB[0] = Student(name: "Lolo", age: 3)
studentsClassB[1] = Student(name: "Lili", age: 4)

var allClasses = [SchoolClass]()
allClasses.append(students : Student(students), speciality : "Sport")
allClasses.append(students : Student(students), speciality : "Art")
```

Why when I want to print the content of allClasses[0].students like this :

```
print("Student list info in 1st class : \(allClasses[0].students)")
```

it just display the type instead of the content values like this :

```
MyProjectName.Student
```

instead of something like :

```
SchoolClass(student: [{"Toto", 1}, {"Titi", 2}], speciality: "Sport")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30896665/5433235

Comment: implement the `CustomStringConvertible ` protocol on your `Student` class.